# Cannot implicitly convert type '...' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<...>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am having issue with my code. I am trying to Select row in my table by ID 
Any help is really appreciate it. Thank you.

```
public FileStreamResult GetPdf(int?  id) 
{
        IList<Requisition> all = new List<Requisition>();
        using (ClinlabEntities dc = new ClinlabEntities()) 
        {
            all = dc.Requisitions.ToList().First(ReqId => ReqId.ReqId == id); 
        }
        WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(source: all, canPage: false, canSort: false);
        string gridHtml = grid.GetHtml(
        columns: grid.Columns(
        grid.Column("FirstName", ""),
        grid.Column("LastName", " "),
            //grid.Column("AccountNo", ""),
        grid.Column("Address", ""),
        grid.Column("City", ""),
        grid.Column("State", ""),
        grid.Column("Zip", "")
        )).ToString();

        string exportData = String.Format("<html><head>{1}</head><body>{1}</body></html>", "<style>table(border-spacing:10px; border-collapse:seperate;)</style>", gridHtml);
        var bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(exportData);
        using (var input = new MemoryStream(bytes)) 
        {
            var output = new MemoryStream();
            var document = new iTextSharp.text.Document(PageSize.LETTER, 15, 0, 0, -15);
            var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, output);
            writer.CloseStream = false;
            document.Open();
            var xmlWorker = iTextSharp.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance();
            xmlWorker.ParseXHtml(writer, document, input, System.Text.Encoding.UTF7);
            document.Close();
            output.Position = 0;
            return new FileStreamResult(output, "Application/Pdf");
        }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you have extra `} }` in your code as well make sure to double check the code format in your .cs file as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assigning the first result of your Requisitions list to the `all` variable, which is expecting `List<Requisition>` instead of the `Requisition` that is returned from `.First()`.

```
IList<Requisition> all = new List<Requisition>();
using (ClinlabEntities dc = new ClinlabEntities()) {
    all = dc.Requisitions.ToList().First(ReqId => ReqId.ReqId == id); 
}
```

The easiest solution is to change `all` to expect a single record:

```
 Requisition all = null;
```

However, this is incredibly inefficient since you are actually loading all of your `Requisition` records into memory and THEN filtering.  You should instead use `.FirstOrDefault()` and forego the `.ToList()`

```
Requisition all = null;
using (ClinlabEntities dc = new ClinlabEntities()) {
    all = dc.Requisitions.FirstOrDefault(ReqId => ReqId.ReqId == id); 
}
```

Comment: Thank You very much for your help. I made the changes as you suggested. but it's give me a different error :(

Comment: @Frank not a problem.  I'd recommend you open a new question with the revised code and error so that your questions are distinct and clear.